# How do I compare Enum values in class to info in main?

Tags: c#, class, enums

This is the class I have:

```
class student
{
    public string Name;
    public int Age;

    public enum Gender
    {
        male,
        female,
        other
    }

    public void Write()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}, Age: {1}, ", Name, Age);   
    }
}
```

And this is the main program:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        student student1 = new student();
        student1.Name = "Dan";
        student1.Age = 15;
        student1.Write();
    }
}
```

When I run the program, the name and age variables from the main program are copied into the function `Write` in the class. I'm trying to do the same with the enum values - I want to write a gender variable in the main program, and add something to the fuction that will also write it, but I dont know how to do it with enum values.

If anyone can help I'd be happy to hear your suggetions.

Comment: Declare a property of type Gender and use it (but first, for your own sake, move the enum declaration outside the class)

Comment: `student.Gender = Gender.other` for instance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a Gender Type to your class:

```
public enum Genders { male, female, other }

class student
{
    public string Name;
    public int Age;
    public Genders Gender;

    public void Write()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}, Age: {1}, Gender: {2}", Name, Age, Gender.ToString());
    }
}

 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        student student1 = new student();
        student1.Name = "Dan";
        student1.Age = 15;
        student1.Gender = Genders.male;
        student1.Write();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you don't use Gender.ToString()? [According to MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.enum.getname(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_3), Enum.GetName(Type, Object) is used to get the name by value (or index)

Comment: @IvanGarcíaTopete do you like it more now? I think it's the same. However i changed it as you suggested, i think it's better..

Comment: Can be shortened to `$"Name: {Name}, Age: {Age}, Gender: {Gender}"`

Comment: @mxmissile yes, but consider mentioning that string interpolation requires C# 6.0 or greater!